# If $T(X) = AX $, $A \subset \mathbb{R^{m \times 1}}, \forall X \in \mathbb{R^{n}},$ Then $T$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, continuity

If $T(X) = AX $, $A \subset \mathbb{R^{m \times 1}}, \forall X \in \mathbb{R^{n}},$ Then $T$ is continuous.

**My thoughts:**

I have proved (or I was helped to prove ) it using the facts that every linear operator is continuous and that every linear operator is bounded in a finite dimensional space.

Now, I want to prove this statement using more elementary tools, like $\epsilon - \delta$ definition, could anyone help me in doing this please?

Comment: Can this be proven without AC?

Comment: Do you mean $A \in \mathbb R^{1 \times n}$?  If not, what does $AX$ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ so $T : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ otherwise it doesn't make much sense.

For $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have

$$\|Tx\|_2^2 = \|Ax\|_2^2= \left\|\left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j\right)_{i=1}^m\right\|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}x_j\right)^2$$
Now apply Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to obtain:

$$\|Tx\|_2^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^m \left(\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^2\right) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2\right) \|x\|_2^2$$

where $\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2$ is a fixed nonnegative constant.

Now we have $$\|Tx-Ty\|_2^2 = \|T(x-y)\|_2^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2\right)\|x-y\|_2^2$$

so $T$ is continuous.

Comment: what is norm_{2}?

Comment: @Smart The euclidean norm, $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{x_1^2+\ldots+x_n^2}$.

Comment: from where you get the second equality in the third line?

Comment: can you give us a proof with $\epsilon -\delta$ ?

Comment: @Smart Definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @Smart Sure. If $A = 0$ then $T = 0$ which is continuous. Assume $A \ne 0$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and set $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2}}$. For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\|x-y\|_2 < \delta$ we have $$\|Tx-Ty\|_2 \le \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2}\|x-y\|_2 <\left(\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2}\right)\delta = \varepsilon $$

Comment: how did you choose your $\delta$?

Comment: @Smart I was having in mind the inequality $$\|Tx-Ty\|_2^2 \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2\right)\|x-y\|_2^2$$